# Apply function at grid cell level across layers of a raster file

Tags: r, netcdf, terra, stars, dplyr

I have a netcdf raster object with multiple layers (time: 30 years * 12 month = 360 steps).

The raster is constituted of multiple grid-cells (say 1000). I want to linearly detrend each month separately and each grid cell separately to obtain a residual raster object with same dimensions as the input.

For a long format data frame with columns **[x,y,value,month,year]**,  I would do it this way:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

```
data %>%
group_by(x, y, month) %>%
      nest() %>%
      mutate(model_trend = map(data,  ~ lm(value ~ year, data = .))) %>%
      mutate(augment_trend  = map(model_trend,  ~ broom::augment(.))) %>%
      unnest(cols = c(augment_trend)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      dplyr::select(x, y, year, month, .resid)
```

I am sure there are much more efficient and similarly easy ways of doing this operation using spatial packages such as `terra, stars` and so forth.

How do I do that?

Comment: Please provide a code example or toy data to work with. It is difficult to provide an answer without data.

Comment: I answered this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73709171/apply-function-at-grid-cell-level-across-layers-of-a-raster-file/73738511#73738511